# Call method on all items of a certain type in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

So I have a collection of objects.  The objects are of differing type, but all of the types derive from a single base class.  I want to iterate through the collection, check for objects of a specific derived type, and call a method in the base class for those objects.  This is what I have:

```
dim DogQuery = From Dog as DogBase in DogCollection
               Where Dog.GetType = GetType(DogBeagle)
               Select Dog

For Each d as DogBase in DogQuery
    d.Feed()
Next
```

...but it seems inelegant.  Especially when...

```
For Each Dog as DogBase in DogCollection
    If Dog.GetType = GetType(DogBeagle) then
        Dog.Feed()
    End If
Next
```

...accomplishes the same thing in (subjectively) tighter code.

My reading on immediate execution suggests that the only way to do what I want is to have the LINQ return a singleton or call something like .ToList().  Is there a way to get immediate execution without needing the extra step?  Or is this just a case of LINQ being overkill for the task at hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) for this.

```
For Each beagle As DogBeagle In DogCollection.OfType(Of Beagle)
    beagle.Feed()
End For
```

Comment: This is even better than what I was looking for.  Thank you kindly!  I will accept as soon as S/O lets me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Deferred/immediate execution isn't relevant here. If you called `ToList()`, that wouldn't change anything.

There are two options to make this simpler though.

Firstly, if you don't need it to be the *exact* `Dog` type, but `DogBeagle` or anything that derives from `DogBeagle`, you could use `OfType`:

```
For Each d As DogBeagle in DogCollection.OfType(Of DogBeagle)()
    d.Feed()
Next
```

If you really do want the exact type, you can use the fact that you're only really using a `Where` clause - you're not transforming the result. As such, LINQ isn't an overkill, but a query expression is... you can just use `Where` directly:

```
For Each d As Dog in DogCollection.Where(Function(x) x.GetType() = GetType(DogBeagle))
    d.Feed()
Next
```